# pass selected record id to href

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, href

I want to use href to call a controller and then display the data in a view. I tested following href and it worked:

```
<a href="/Samples/Create?id=@Model.ID" class="btn btn-primary btn">Add Sample/a>
```

However, the id I need to pass is a selected record id that I can get by using Ajax method:

```
var id = $('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id');
```

The problem is that I can not pass the id to href since the id is not view-level variable.

The question is then: what is the syntax to express this selected (radio button) id inside the href?  I tried to copy and paste `$('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id')` into the href to get:

```
<a href="/Samples/Create?id=$('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id')" class="btn btn-primary btn">Add Sample/a>.
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the double quotes around "RadioRequest"

```
<a href="/Samples/Create?id=$('[name=\"RadioRequest\"]:checked').prop('id')" class="btn btn-primary btn">Add Sample/a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kirby. I tried many different combinations. Did not work.

Comment: @user3266771 - No problem, I actually was not sure how the href link was being created so it was a quick 'try'. Is this a matter of creating the proper link or getting the value of the Radio Request value (id)? I'd be happy to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty certain this has been answered several times on SO, but just for lulz ill provide some answers.

First, you wont be able to embed javascript in to the href. Unless you use javascript to change the href attribute, its going to remain static.

The easiest thing to do is wrap this in a form. It may or may not be semantically correct in your context, but if you wrap this in a form, it will automatically provide your form fields (including the value of the selected radio button.

Here is a sample of submitting it as a form. You will have to make apply it to your code.

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <form name="form1" action="" method="get">
      <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1"/> <!--You will need to set value dynamically. 
      <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2"/> You could also change name="rad" to name="id" if you specifically need that to be the name -->

      <a href="#" onclick="form1.submit()">Submit</a>
   </form>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Essentially you just give the radio buttons the same name. The value provided will be whatever is selected (value could be your id). The action attribute is the uri you want to send it to, and method="get" ensures that it is provided in the querystring. The Anchor tag doesn't have a url, it just performs a submit on the form.

If you want to do it strictly in javascript, there are a few routes you could take.

For one, you could have an event handler for onclick of the radio buttons that changes the href attribute of the anchor tag when you select it.

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var url = "http://www.yahoo.com";

      function ChangeUrl(val){

        var newUrl = url + "?=" + val;
        document.getElementById("myLink").href=newUrl;
      }
 </script>
   <input type="radio" name="rad" onclick="ChangeUrl(1)"/> <!-- onclick should be onselect, but I couldn't get that working in my test code so I went with what works. -->
   <input type="radio" name="rad" onclick="ChangeUrl(2)"/>

   <a href="#" id="myLink">Submit</a>

 </body>

</html>
```

Again you will need to put some thought in to how you do it in your code, but this is a general idea.

Comment: Hi bsayegh,  Thanks very much for your help.  I need to digest what you suggested and see if it works for me.   I did get it working with Ajax method using var id = $('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id'); url: "/Samples/Create/" + id;   I thought it was too complicated.  it would be much simplier if I could get id dynamically inside href.  Thanks for your help. I did not have to try this route.